# Kotlin set one listener for multiple controls

Tags: android, kotlin, event-listener

I'm approaching to kotlin (and to mobile coding)
I'm trying to set one listener to run the same function on click on everyone of multiple textView.
I found the below code on SO (sorry for missing link: I was unable to find it again)
but i get error on the last "it", when I try to pass the textView to the function.

```
    val txtV_Ans1 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer1) as TextView
    val txtV_Ans2 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer2) as TextView
    val txtV_Ans3 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer3) as TextView
    val txtV_Ans4 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer4) as TextView

    val txtVs_Ans = arrayListOf(
        txtV_Ans1,
        txtV_Ans2,
        txtV_Ans3,
        txtV_Ans4
    )
    txtVs_Ans.forEach { it.setOnClickListener { txtV_Fill(it, "You clicked here")} }

fun txtV_Fill(txtV: TextView, txtToInsert: String){
    txtV.text = txtToInsert
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided seems mostly correct, but you're encountering an issue because the it reference within the forEach lambda doesn't refer to a TextView in this context. You should use a more explicit approach to pass the TextView to the `txtV_Fill` function.

```
val txtV_Ans1 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer1) as TextView
val txtV_Ans2 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer2) as TextView
val txtV_Ans3 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer3) as TextView
val txtV_Ans4 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer4) as TextView

val txtVs_Ans = arrayListOf(
    txtV_Ans1,
    txtV_Ans2,
    txtV_Ans3,
    txtV_Ans4
)

txtVs_Ans.forEach { txtView ->
    txtView.setOnClickListener { 
        txtV_Fill(txtView, "You clicked here")
    }
}

fun txtV_Fill(txtV: TextView, txtToInsert: String) {
    txtV.text = txtToInsert
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote it but looking around I found this https://blog.gouline.net/kotlin-bits-for-loops-vs-foreach-30548d7472a5 @genespos

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SharedClickListener**. Clean usage

```
    val sharedClickListener = View.OnClickListener {
      txtV_Fill(this, "You clicked here") // or this as TextView
    }
    val txtV_Ans1 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer1) as TextView
    val txtV_Ans2 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer2) as TextView
    val txtV_Ans3 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer3) as TextView
    val txtV_Ans4 = findViewById(R.id.txtV_Aswer4) as TextView

    txtV_Ans1.setOnClickListener(sharedClickListener)
    txtV_Ans2.setOnClickListener(sharedClickListener)
    txtV_Ans3.setOnClickListener(sharedClickListener)
    txtV_Ans4.setOnClickListener(sharedClickListener)

fun txtV_Fill(txtV: TextView, txtToInsert: String){
    txtV.text = txtToInsert
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, and pass as many TextViews as you want.

```
private fun setListeners(vararg textViews: TextView) {
        textViews.forEach { textView ->
            textView.setOnClickListener {
                textView.textFill("You clicked here")
            }
        }
    }

private fun TextView.textFill(textToInsert: String) {
        text = textToInsert
    }
```

Example:

```
setListeners(txtV_Ans1, txtV_Ans2, txtV_Ans3, txtV_Ans4)
```